# Running automation scripts for Protractor in Visual Studio 2017, when written in VS code editor

Tags: protractor

I have a Protractor automation project, having a customised framework, written in VS code. Now I want to run the same scripts through Visual Studio 2017. Please help, how to run the scripts from Visual Studio.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, provide more information on what you tried so far.

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask center and correct your question.